# How to make Laravel 6 authorization that checks for 4 different usertype

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to edit this tutorial with no avail. This works if you only have a user and an admin. What I need to have is to make it check for 4 possible usertypes.

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-multi-auth-authentication-tutorialexample.html

Comment: Please, add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question instead link to external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment on Ruben Danielyan's answer, it seems like you're trying to use `is_admin` as your role identifier by using 1 and 2, however if you used the tutorial's migration this will not work since is_admin is a boolean. So you would have to change in the migration file to `$table->integer('is_admin')->nullable();`

Edit:

As per porloscerros said, you should also perhaps rename `is_admin` to a more appropriate name like `role_id` or `role_category` since fields starting with `is_` are generally used for boolean value to represent whether a record is or is not in one specific state or category (like is_active, is_hidden, or is_discounted)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my questions. I will change my codes now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use roles and permissions package to assign roles to your registered users,`spatie/laravel-permission` is my best choice. Then you can redirect user depending on his role

The code from your tutorial

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    ...
    $user = auth()->user();
        if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.home');
        }else if ($user->hasRole('modertor')){
            return redirect()->route('moderator.home');
        }else if ($user->hasRole('translator')){
            return redirect()->route('translator.home');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
}
```

Comment: is spatie an extention?

Sorry First time Encountering that.

Comment: **Use of undefined constant ‘home’ - assumed '‘home’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)**

This is the error when i implement it.

Comment: **This is my Code right now**


`if(auth()->attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'])))
        {
            if (auth()->user()->is_admin == 1) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.home');
            }elseif (auth()->user()->is_admin == 2) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.home');
            }else{
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }else{`

Comment: is_admin column is boolean, it accepts only 0 or 1, if you use is_admin=2 it will be not conceptual

Comment: what should i use? it is working now but im still using boolean.

Comment: search for spatie/laravel-permission, read the docs, install and use, it's easy

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.

All you have to do is to add a guard.

Open `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php` and change your boot method

```
public function boot(){
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Auth::viaRequest('admin', function ($request) {
         return Admin::where('token', $request->token)->first();
    });
}
```

After that attach this guard to your model in `config/auth.php`.

```
...
'guards' => [
    'web' => ['driver' => 'session','provider' => 'users',],
    'admin' => ['driver' => 'session','provider' => 'admins',],
],
...
'providers' => [
    'users' => ['driver' => 'eloquent','model' => App\User::class,],
    'admins' => ['driver' => 'eloquent','model' => App\Admin::class,],
],
...
```

Now you may use `auth:admin` middleware on a route to check if `admin` is logged in before reaching that route.